# Expand $\frac{1}{z-i}$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

> Expand $\frac{1}{z-i}$ to power series around $z_0=1$ and find the radius of convergence

$$\frac{1}{z-i}=\frac{1}{(z-1)+1-i}=\frac{1}{1-i}\cdot\frac{1}{1+\frac{z-1}{1-i}}=\frac{1}{1-i}\cdot\frac{1}{1-(-\frac{z-1}{1-i})}=\frac{1}{1-i}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-\frac{z-1}{1-i})^n=\frac{1}{1-i}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(1-i)^n}(z-1)^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(1-i)^{n+1}}(z-1)^n$$

If the above is correct how should I find the radius of convergence? I need to bring it to $\sum a_nz^n$ and use $\lim_{n\to\infty}|\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}|$?

Comment: You are fine. You don't need to bring it to $\sum a_n z^n$. You can calculate the radius without that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An approach different from using the ratio test. Observe that when you used:

$$
\frac{1}{1-a} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n
$$

you assumed that $|a| < 1$. In your case:

$$
|\frac{z-1}{1-i}|<1
$$

a region in $\mathbb{C}$ that has radius $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: $|1-i| = \sqrt 2$ and the radius of convergence of the geometric series that you used is 1.

Comment: Just figure it out, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you did is correct. Now\begin{align*}\lim_{n\in\mathbb N}\left|\frac{\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(1-i)^{n+2}}}{\frac{(-1)^n}{(1-i)^{n+1}}}\right|&=\lim_{n\in\mathbb N}\frac{\sqrt2^{n+1}}{\sqrt{2}^{n+2}}\\&=\frac1{\sqrt2}.\end{align*}Therefore, the radius of convergence is $\sqrt2$.

Comment: Should not the fraction be flipped? the n power divided by n+1 ?

Comment: @gbox That would work, too. I have the habit of computing the limit $l=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|$; then the radius of convergence is $l^{-1}$; that's what I did. Or you can compute the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}\right|$, which will be the radius of convergence.